# What does class=" " do?

Tags: html, css, class

What does class=" " do if there is nothing being referenced between the quotes?

It comes from the HTML of http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

```
<a class="" href="/cv>my profile</a>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create the texture behind the grey button.

[image: image from navigation menu careers.stackoverflow.com]

Comment: It sets the class name of the element to the empty string. What else would it do?

Comment: @BoltClock: Haha, some guys want an easy up vote :)

Comment: @BoltClock And that was in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They didn't make it grey from the class="". Just ignore that it might as well not even be there.

This is how it's grey:

```
#header > #nav-container > ul.careers > li > a {
color: white;
background: #9C9C9C url(/Content/Img/header-nav-bg.png) repeat-x;
border-right: 1px solid #939393;
border-left: 1px solid #939393;
padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

That translates to the link under a list item under the list with class name "careers" which is under the element of id "nav-container" which is under the element with id "header"

Answer (score 4):

It means it doesn't have a class. In fact, it's equivalent to not having the `class` attribute at all.

That said, it *may* have been explicitly defined as empty because the server-side code that generates the links isn't outputting anything to the `class` attribute between the quotes.

> I'm trying to figure out how to create the texture behind the grey button.

That's just a background image.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing.

According to chrome, the rules come from

```
#header > #nav-container > ul.careers > li > a {
 color: #fff;
 background: #9c9c9c url(/Content/Img/header-nav-bg.png) repeat-x;
 border-right: 1px solid #939393;
 border-left: 1px solid #939393;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't do anything and can safely be removed, unless JavaScript relies on the `className` property having a non-null value all the time, which I doubt.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do anything. There's no class defined. It will make no difference if you remove it, UNLESS there is javascript which relies on a class attribute being present. If so, the javascript may break on a `null` object.

Another possible reason for it's existence is that it's been generated by the webapp, cms or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Setting class to an empty string applies no classes to your element.

If you want to style the button, you would need something like the following:

```
.stripes {
   display: block;
   padding: 2px;
   background: url(/path/to/stripy/background.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
   width: 30px;
   height: 10px;
}
```

And then you would apply the stripes class to the anchor element.

```
<a class="stripes" href="/">linky</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does nothing. Probably a remnant of the CMS.

Here's how Chrome sees the styles on that grey button.

```
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: #9C9C9C;
  background-image: url(http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/header-nav-bg.png);
  background-origin: padding-box;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-color: #939393;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #939393;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  clear: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 18px;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0px;
  zoom: 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing!It doesn't matter if you put an empty value.
In this case(button 'my profile') there is a css expression to cause this effect:

```
#header > #nav-container > ul.careers > li > a {
  /*properties like color, size, background, etc...*/
}
```

These '>' are used to follow an hierarchy. Example:

```
#div > a {
  color:blue;
  /*put your background*/    
}
```

causes:

```
<a>Nothing happens</a>
<div>
 <a>I'm blue</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It ensures that "class" is empty ;)

Comment: Not exactly. It could be changed in Javascript.

Comment: I meant at the start time! A browser could use a "standard class" if class is not specified. So, this ensures it is empty ;)

Answer (score 0):

it does absolutly nothing :)

they add the style by selecting the element itself like here for example:

```
#header > #nav-container > ul.careers > li > a {background:grey};
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not do anything, but all previously assigned styles stay the same.